# Querying for days where bookings already exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a bookings table, I would like to query to find out which days already have future bookings on them, for a particular space.

```
id  buyerid    startdatetime            enddatetime        vehicle spaceid status
2      5    2014-04-29 09:00:00     2014-04-29 21:00:00       2       1      1
3      6    2014-05-03 13:00:00     2014-05-03 18:00:00       3       1      1
```

So that the result is like the following (true means that at least one booking exists on that day):

```
mon   tue   wed   thur   fri   sat   sun
true  true false false false true false
```

So in my exanmple there is a booking on saturday 3rd may, so the sat column in the result would be true because there is a booking on a saturday. The tue column would also be true because there is a booking on the 29th april, which is a tuesday. Lets assume there are no future bookings for the space on any day that is a wednesday, so wednesday column is false.

Comment: and what is the problem ?

Comment: Do you need the results only for the current/next week or the resultset mean something different?

Comment: I want to query on a space for all future bookings and return mon - sat columns. So in my exanmple there is a booking on saturday 3rd may, so the sat column in the result would be true because there is a booking on a saturday. The tue column would also be true because there is a booking on the 29th

Answer (score -1):

From what I can gather you are trying to do something like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE datetime='$datetime'");
$taken = mysql_num_rows($query); //Checks how many bookings are made using that date time

if($taken >= 1){return false;}else{return true;}
```

If this is not what you want then please comment with more information.

Comment: Minus 1.  datetime = '$datetime' does not get future bookings.

Comment: I was getting the datetime for a specific day as he said they need to find how many bookings for each day.

Comment: You are also disregarding the time portion of the datetime field.